# Build a CRUD App with React Hooks and the Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, crud, react-context

I want to build a CRUD App with React Hooks and the Context API. my problem is in the `EditUser` component. when I click on edit button to edit user it doesn't show anything on the page and in the console I have this error:

`selectedUser` is undefined for this part `value={selectedUser.name} name="name"`

```
<Input type='text' palaceholder="Enter Name"
    value={selectedUser.name} name="name"
    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange("name", e.target.value)}
></Input>
```

thank you for your help!

Here is my components:

`GlobalState` component:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'

//Initial State
const initialState = {
    users: [

    ]
}
//Create Context
export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

//Provider Component
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

    //Actions
    const removeUser = (id) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'REMOVE_USER',
            payload: id
        })
    }
    const addUser = (user) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_USER',
            payload: user
        })
    }
    const editUser = (user) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'EDIT_USER',
            payload: user
        })
    }
    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ users: state.users, removeUser, addUser, editUser }}>
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

`AppReducer` component:

```
export default (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REMOVE_USER':
            return {
                users: state.users.filter(user => {
                    return user.id !== action.payload
                })
            }
        case 'ADD_USER':
            return {
                users: [action.payload, ...state.users]
            }
        case 'EDIT_USER':
            const updateUser = action.payload;

            const editUsers = state.users.map(user => {
                if (user.id === updateUser.id) {
                    return updateUser
                }
                return user
            });
            return {
                users: editUsers 
            }
        default:
            return state
    }


}
```

and finally`EditUser`component:

```
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState';
import React,{ useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
    Button
} from 'reactstrap'


const EditUser = () => {

    const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({
        id: "",
        name:""
    })
    const { users, editUser } = useContext(GlobalContext)
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const { currentUserId } = useParams();


    useEffect(() => {
        const userId = currentUserId;
        const selectedUser = users.find(user => user.id === parseInt(userId));
        setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
    }, [currentUserId, users])

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        editUser(selectedUser);
        navigate('/');
    };

    const handleOnChange = (userKey, newValue) => {
        setSelectedUser({ ...selectedUser, [userKey]: newValue })
    };


    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormGroup>
                <Label>Name</Label>
                <Input type='text' palaceholder="Enter Name"
                    value={selectedUser.name} name="name"
                    onChange={(e) => handleOnChange("name", e.target.value)}
                ></Input>
            </FormGroup>
            <Button type='submit' className='bg-success '>Edit Name</Button>
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger m-2">Cancel</Link>

        </Form>
    );
}

export default EditUser;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. `Array.prototype.find` returns either the first match in the array or undefined if there are no matches. If there is no match found in the array you probably don't want to update the `selectedUser` state to undefined.
2. If/when the `selectedUser` state is undefined attempting to access properties of undefined will throw the error you see. Use a null-check/guard-clause or the Optional Chaining Operator to prevent accidental accesses into potentially null or undefined objects.

## Solution

Only enqueue `selectedUser` updates if there is a matching user to update with.

```
const { currentUserId } = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  const userId = currentUserId;
  const selectedUser = users.find(user => String(user.id) === userId);
  if (selectedUser) {
    setSelectedUser(selectedUser);
  }
}, [currentUserId, users]);
```

Protect the `currentUser` nested property accesses, and provide a valid defined fallback value for the `input` so it doesn't throw errors switching between controlled and uncontrolled. Refactor the `handleOnChange` to consume the `onChange` event and destructure the input name and value from it, and use a functional state update to update from the previous state.

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setSelectedUser(selectedUser => ({
    ...selectedUser,
    [name]: value
  }));
};

...

<FormGroup>
  <Label>Name</Label>
  <Input
    type='text'
    palaceholder="Enter Name"
    value={selectedUser?.name ?? ""}
    name="name"
    onChange={handleOnChange}
  />
</FormGroup>
```

### Additional Suggestion

This is only a minor point about the reducer function logic. What you have is ok since the only property the `userReducer` has is a `users` property, but it's a reducer function convention to also shallow copy the previous `state` as well.

Example:

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_USER':
      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload),
      }

    case 'ADD_USER':
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [action.payload, ...state.users],
      }

    case 'EDIT_USER':
      const updateUser = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        users: state.users.map(user => user.id === updateUser.id
          ? updateUser
          : user
        ), 
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you for your help. but there is another problem: when i click on edit button after i edit the user it goes to home page but edit doesn't show on the home page and the user remain with no changes!

Comment: @Negin I see. Nothing overtly sticks out as an issue in the code you've shared for dispatching the edit user action and routing/navigation. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-oskar-6jt32w?file=/src/components/AddUser.js). thank you.

Comment: @Negin The edit route's param is `id`, not `currentUserId`, `currentUserId` is undefined in the component so it's unable to find a match. In the `EditUser` component use `const { id } = useParams();` and rename all `currentUserId` usages to `id`. https://codesandbox.io/s/build-a-crud-app-with-react-hooks-and-the-context-api-14lg2i